Functions in set_graph_function not getting traced
I only want to trace function dev_gro_receive() with frace. I've added the following:
# cat /sys/kernel/tracing/set_graph_function
dev_gro_receive

When I cat /sys/kernel/trace, I don't see dev_gro_receive() and see other functions in the output, such as idle_cpu(). I have function_graph tracing enabled.
# cat /sys/kernel/tracing/current_tracer
function_graph

I have tracing enable:
# cat /sys/kernel/tracing/tracing_on
1

I have verified that dev_gro_receive() is getting called with bpftrace:
sudo bpftrace -e 'kprobe:dev_gro_receive {printf("Got packet\n");}'

Why am I not able to trace a specific function using ftrace?

You cannot change set_graph_function on the fly. You must

Set tracing off: echo nop > current_tracer
Set set_graph_function to what you want, i.e., echo dev_gro_receive > set_graph_function
Enable the function graph tracer echo graph_function > current_tracer

This also holds if you are excluding functions by using  set_graph_notrace
